# Why access control and authorization dont work together in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, httpd, httpd.conf

I have a Centos Linux server with Apache 2.4 and having multiple virtual sites. I spent a lot of time implementing access control on the basis of ip but failed. I now realized that access control works if no authorization is present in .htaccess in the virtual host.

My question is how to make it both work? i.e. Only visitors from specific ip's are allowed to visit the site and offered to enter .htaccess/.htpasswd password.

Here are my virtual host settings.

```
Alias /test "/home/test"
<Directory "/home/test">
    Options All
    Require all denied
    AllowOverride All
    Require ip w.x.y.z
 </Directory>
```

and .htaccess file.

```
AuthUserFile /home/test/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Welcome user"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

If I remove .htaccess and .htpasswd then I get Forbidden. With both settings enabled I was expecting that it will offer username and password to only users from valid ips. Why it is not? How to make both work together? thanks.
[image]